# Filtering out one possibility in a union type

Tags: typescript, typechecking

The following does not compile:

```
function f(n: number): (number|null) {
  return n > 0 ? n : null;
}

function g(a: number[]): number[] {
  return a.map(f).filter(n => n);
}
```

The problem is, the compiler does not understand the semantics of filter(), and does not realize that it will omit all falsey entries in the list.  As a result, it fails with "Type '(number | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'."

The following does work:

```
function g(n: number[]): number[] {
  return n.map(f).filter(n => n).map(n => n!);
```

}

but goes through a meaningless loop.  This works too

```
function g(a: number[]): number[] {
  return a.map(f).filter(n => n) as number[];
}
```

but a cast like that will obscure a multitude of sins.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you want `filter()` to return an array of different type, you have to give it a type guard as an argument. See also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18562

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the filtering method out and use Type Guards to make it a little more precise.

Like so:

```
function f(n: number): (number | null) {
    return n > 0 ? n : null
}

function hasValue(n: number | null): n is number {
    return !!n
}

function g(a: number[]): number[] {
    return a.map(f).filter(hasValue)
}
```

Note. !!n will filter out 0 as well so not strictly correct but suitable for highlighting type guards